# Simplifying dy/(y+z) = dz/(y-z) for integration

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

This is a part of a textbook solution. I haven't understood how they simplified dy/(y+z) = dz/(y-z) and got their answer.

I just did (y-z)dy = (y+z)dz and integrated it which gave me z^2 - y^2 + 4yz = c1

Can anyone explain please?

Comment: The line after the implication sign is wrong, there should be no $\frac12$s. But the answer given is correct (though of course not the integral of the incorrect expression!) What a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that
$$
{dy \over y + z} = {dz \over y - z}
$$
which yields
$$
 (y - z) dy = (y + z) dz  
$$

Simplifying, we get
$$
y dy - z dy = y dz + z dz 
$$
or
$$
y dy - z dz = y dz + z dy = d(yz)
$$

Rearranging terms, we get
$$
y dy - z dz - d(yz) = 0
$$

Integrating both sides, we get
$$
{y^2 \over 2} - {z^2 \over 2} - y z = k
$$
where $k$ is an integration constant.

Thus,
$$
y^2 - z^2 - 2 y z = C_1,
$$
where $C_1 = 2 k$ is an integration constant.